# Django - Query To Check if Item In Many to Many Relationship Field

Tags: python, django

I have a User and a Deal model as shown below.  The User model has a 'favorites' field which is a many to many relationship with the Deal model.

I'm trying to allow a user to save a Deal to their Favorites.  I have tested both the `favorite` and `remove_favorite` views and both are doing exactly what they are supposed to do.

**Here's My Issue** -- The conditional statement on my `deal_detail.html` page which checks to see if the current deal on the page is a favorite of the logged in user doesn't seem to be working.

```
{% if deal_detail in user.favorites %}
```

I'm just having a hard time wrapping my head around how to check this.

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, error_messages={'unique':"This email has already been registered."})
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='', blank=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Deal, related_name='favorited_by', null=True, blank=True)

class Deal(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(default='')
```

My corresponding views look like this:

```
    def deal_by_detail(request, slug):
        deal_detail = Deal.objects.get(slug=slug)
        user = request.user
        return render(request, 'deals/deal_detail.html', {'deal_detail': deal_detail, 'user': user})

    @login_required(login_url='/accounts/sign_in/')
    def favorite(request, pk):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            favorite = Deal.objects.get(pk=pk)
            user = request.user
            user.favorites.add(favorite)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Deal Favorited.')
            return redirect('home')

    @login_required(login_url='/accounts/sign_in/')
    def remove_favorite(request, pk):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            favorite = Deal.objects.get(pk=pk)
            user = request.user
            user.favorites.remove(favorite)
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Deal Removed.')
            return redirect('home')
```

My form `deal_detail.html` looks like this:

```
  {% if deal_detail in user.favorites %}

     <form id="favorite{{deal_detail.id}}" method="POST" action="{% url 'deals:favorite' deal_detail.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" />
       <input type="submit" value="Add Deal to Favorites" />
    </form>

     {% else %}

      <form id="favorite{{deal_detail.id}}" method="POST" action="{% url 'deals:remove_favorite' deal_detail.id %}">
      {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="hidden" name="supporttype" />
       <input type="submit" value="Remove Deal From Favorites" />
      </form>
```

{% endif %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are just missing the .all after the manytomany field. Then it should be able to run the check and function as you intended

```
{% if deal_detail in user.favorites.all %}
```